# how would i make two empty lists and put them into a dictinary so that the names and numbers are associated and take user inputs

Tags: dictionary, input, empty-list

the objcetive it to have an empty list that gets inputs from a user and has a number associated with it. below is what ive tried:

```
name = []
number =[]
counter = 0
while counter != 3:
  name_grade = {
    name.append(str(input("enter your name: "))) : number.append(int(input("enter your number: ")))
    }
counter= counter + 1
print(name_number)
```

but i just get:

> {None: None}

is there a better way of doing this and how would i do this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because there's no variable or dictionary in your code named **name_number**.
The basic way to do this would be as follows:

```
name = []
number =[]
counter = 0
name_grade = {}

while counter != 3:
    #taking the inputs:
    name_inp = str(input("Enter your name: "))
    number_inp = int(input("Enter your number: "))
    
    #adding to the dictionary
    name_grade[name_inp] = number_inp
    
    #adding to the lists
    name.append(name_inp)
    number.append(number_inp)
 
    counter= counter + 1
print(name_grade)
```

Comment: out of curiosity what does the section on the 12th line: name_grade[name_inp] mean and how is it used?

Comment: It makes the name_inp as a key in the dictionary with number_inp as its value, if the key was not already present in the dictionary. But if t was already present in the dictionary, then the value gets updated. 
also, if it the answer helped you, can you please upvote the answer.